# fancyhdr works only once

Tags: fancyhdr, books

I'm using the `fancyhdr` package to make sure the page number is always positioned at the same point, for example to the right of the footer. But there is a problem: this works only for the first page of a chapter, while for the remaining pages it's displayed in the upper right corner

Compiler: Texmaker 4.5

Format: PDFLaTeX

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}%fancy plain   we redefine style plain
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\parindent 1cm
\parskip 0.2cm
\topmargin 0.2cm
\oddsidemargin 1cm
\evensidemargin 0.5cm
\textwidth 15cm
\textheight 21cm
\voffset = -2cm
\footskip = 80pt

\def\R{\mathbb{ R}}
\def\S{\mathbb{ S}}
\def\I{\mathbb{ I}}

\title{Laboratorio di Chimica Organica II}

\author{The Alchemyst}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Index}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Identificazione di una sostanza organica incognita}\normalsize
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\newpage
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to use the explicit layout settings?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you need to add `\pagestyle{plain}` before or just after `\begin{document}`

Comment: `\paperheight` etc. settings. This should be done with `geometry`.Also don't use such things like `\def\S`... nor the package `times` etc.. TeXMaker is no compiler but the editor, `pdflatex` is the compiler.

Comment: @touhami: Sorry, didn't see your comment when answering

Comment: ***Never*** set `\voffset` or `\hoffset`.

Comment: @egreg What can I do if I need more space horizontally?

Comment: @user3204810 Use `geometry` as recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that `\fancypagestyle{<style>}{<definition>}` takes *two* arguments. The first is the `<style>` to be (re)defined while the second is filled with the new `<definition>`.

In your code the second argument is not explicitly defined by a balanced set of braces `{`...`}`, so TeX assumes it will be the next *token*. That is,

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
...
```

is just the same as

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\lhead}
{}
\chead{}
...
```

which doesn't really do anything. Moreover, using

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\newpage
```

would redefine the `plain` page style to issue a `\newpage` (which doesn't help either).

To rectify your definitions and use,

1. Properly specify the redefinition of the `plain` page style using a set of balanced braces `{`...`}`, and
2. Use/set the `plain` page style using `\pagestyle{plain}` to have it as the default page style (other than issue of `\thispagestyle`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \lhead{}
  \chead{}
  \rhead{}
  \lfoot{}
  \cfoot{}
  \rfoot{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\title{Document title}
\author{Document author}
\date{Document date}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Amongst some other issues: `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}` does not enable the pagestyle, it redefines it.

One has to use `\pagestyle{plain}` to enable this.

Don't use such setups like `\textheight 20cm` etc. -- this is error prone; Use the `geometry` package for layout changes.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%fancy plain   we redefine style plain
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\parindent 1cm
\parskip 0.2cm
\topmargin 0.2cm
\oddsidemargin 1cm
\evensidemargin 0.5cm
\textwidth 15cm
\textheight 21cm
\voffset = -2cm
\footskip = 80pt

\def\R{\mathbb{ R}} % Oh my
\def\S{\mathbb{ S}}
\def\I{\mathbb{ I}}

\title{Laboratorio di Chimica Organica II}

\author{The Alchemyst}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Index}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Identificazione di una sostanza organica incognita}\normalsize
\pagestyle{plain}
\clearpage
\lipsum

\end{document}
```